# Django + Postgres: OperationalError FATAL: sorry, too many clients already (as a result of a deliberate attack)

Tags: django, postgresql

There are many similar questions on Stackoverflow but they do not address my particular case. The problem is that there are deliberate attacks on the website with many simultaneous requests. I have mimicked these attacks running the following command:

```
ab -k -c 150 -n 90000 'https://www.mywebsite.com/'
```

The website gets down with the following error:

```
OperationalError at /
FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

The number of max connections allowed on my Postgres instance is 100. Raising it, as recommended in most answers on Stackoverflow, is pointless, as there might be significantly higher numbers of requests during the deliberate attacks which we have been suffering lately.

I have tried remedying the issue by creating a special middleware caching the number of requests:

```
from ipware import get_client_ip

class IPMiddleware:
    REQUEST_PERIOD_IN_SECONDS = 10
    MAX_REQUESTS_IN_PERIOD = 100
    TOO_MANY_REQUESTS_BAN_PERIOD_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 2

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        try:
            ip, is_routable = get_client_ip(request)
            if ip:

                if cache.get(f'ip_is_banned_{ip}', False):
                    raise PermissionDenied()

                cache_key = f'requests_made_{ip}'
                try:
                    cache.incr(cache_key)
                except ValueError:
                    cache.set(cache_key, 1, self.REQUEST_PERIOD_IN_SECONDS)

                requests_made = cache.get(cache_key)
                if requests_made > self.MAX_REQUESTS_IN_PERIOD:
                    cache.set(f'ip_is_banned_{ip}', True, self.TOO_MANY_REQUESTS_BAN_PERIOD_IN_SECONDS)

        except:
            pass

        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

The order of my middlewares in settings.py is the following:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'mywebsite.middlewares.CustomLocaleMiddleware',
    'mywebsite.middlewares.IPMiddleware',
    'maintenancemode.middleware.MaintenanceModeMiddleware',
]
```

The idea is to ban an IP that has made more than a number of requests within a period of time (e.g. 100 requests in 10 seconds). Then, if the IP is banned, PermissionDenied() is raised.

The cache logic works and the IP is getting banned. However, this does not prevent the simultaneous requests from hitting the database. I have tested it by changing the number of requests in a/b testing: it works fine with 50 requests but breaks the site with 150 requests.

Is there any efficient way to counteract such attacks except using Cloudflare?

Comment: Make your middleware the first?

Comment: another idea would be to implement the screening at a different layer. For example if you're using NGINX, you could use limit_req_zone: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html#limit_req_zone

Comment: I think it doesn't matter how many requests you are getting it depends on how many process and threads you are running on you application each thread open up a connection and then close it (if `CONN_MAX_AGE` is not specified) and if you are running your application with 10 threads on 4 process i think you will have 40 connections open at maximum, celery and other thirdparty which run on different threads will open up their own connections .. is your application the only client to your database? [document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/databases/#caveats)

Comment: @aaron This doesn't work as I need to access request.user in the middleware. Therfore, making IPMiddleware first results in AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'user'.

Comment: @AmirHeshmati The problems arise when there are many requests, not when apache is creating processes/threads.

Comment: Use a DB connection pool?

Comment: So i haven't served python with Apache but the [document](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/processes-and-threading.html) mentions that mod_wsgi will created thread and processes based on how many request it is receiving if no limit is specified . also you have control over how many process and child process apache creates based on which mode apache is running on [also take a look at this](https://serverfault.com/questions/81022/how-many-processes-should-i-specify-in-a-wsgidaemonprocess-while-running-django)
so if you are receiving many request there will be many threads

Comment: And when you have many threads then there are many simultaneous db connections so no matter how high you set the db connection size you will reach a limit.. if there are bursts of request you can use queuing which i think apache can handle if your throughput is a lot i suggest maybe database replication and caching to make response times faster in order to release db connection quicker but defiantly set limits on Apache since if you lack resources your application will flood the server making your database even slower to response hence more prone to the error you are getting

Comment: I also suggest taking DDOS protection not into your application. it makes sense to throttle on application side when the application logic is required (e.g. each user can update his profile 10 times a day)  but generally IMO it's better to let the application be last step for these kind of protection and let network level and firewalls handle DDOS attacks. for example cloudflare has a set of free tools for DDOS protection

Comment: @AmirHeshmati Thanks. Unfortunately, caching is not an option because my website hosts tens of millions of pages each dependent on the database: it is impossible to hold this size of cached data. As for Cloudflare, I am aware of this option, but it slows down everything for the user and for Googlebot, so I am trying to find another option.

Comment: Use a DB connection pool?

Comment: @whp Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Running ab -k -c 150 -n 90000 'mywebsite.com' is still getting the website down.

Comment: @aaron I have been reading about PgBouncer. As far as I understand, it will not help against the attacks, only increasing the limit of max connections, which is of little help.

Comment: What kind of solution do you expect if your `IPMiddleware` requires querying `user`?

Comment: @aaron I don't stick to the middleware solution, so any other solution that works.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use nginx? Then you better limit the number of queries from the same ip using nginx. Django is too slow for that, imho.
https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Running ab -k -c 150 -n 90000 'https://www.mywebsite.com/' is still getting the website down.